# How to enable Neo4j REST Streaming with spring-data-neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using [spring-data-neo4j](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j) to access the Neo4j database. I want to enable REST [streaming](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/rest-api-streaming.html) for improving the performance of my Neo4j interactions.

Can anyone please guide me on how to leverage streaming via spring-data-neo4j? i.e. How do I tell spring data to send the `'stream=true'` header in every REST request to the Neo4j server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is already enabled by default.

You can control it by the System property: `org.neo4j.rest.stream=true`

https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding#configuration-system-properties